# Difference between ◯◯を掃除 and ◯◯に掃除

Tags: grammar, particles

What's the difference between ◯◯**を**掃除 and ◯◯**に**掃除？

Trying to understand the following, which using "に"

> 引き続き執筆。合間のリフレッシュ**に**掃除

Comment: @Dave Sorry. I edited the title. I tried to make it better. It was even worse. Please see the edit history if that makes any difference to your consideration.

Comment: It would be amazing what you would learn if you just opened ANY beginner Japanese textbook instead of "language hacking" using Twitter.

Comment: My question was fine the way it was. I'm going to fix it and then select a best answer before someone else can mess it up again. Thanks sawa (rolls eyes)

Comment: @language hacker: Rushing to accept an answer so as to protect a question is indicative of a complete misuse of the site and a misunderstanding of its purpose. Any question that requires such behaviour is clearly flawed, as any normal question should be able to sit indefinitely until the *right* answer comes along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you meant `掃除する`.

In `部屋を掃除する`, `部屋` is the object to be cleaned.

There can be sources of a `...に` phrase that are **not directly relevant** to this predicate:

- Time: `3時に掃除する`
- The subject of a causative: `その人に掃除させる`
- An adverbial phrase expressing the purpose (can be translated as 'as'): `気晴らしに掃除する`

Comment: I saw this: 引き続き執筆。合間のリフレッシュに掃除♪( ´▽｀)

Comment: @langauge_hacker The context you gave was insufficient. I changed the answer. Your example with リフレッシュ is the last one.

Comment: So Aに掃除する is the same thing as Aのために掃除する？

Comment: @langauge_hacker In this particular context, they are almost the same.